# How to get the overall function FROM the imaginary part

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I've come across this interesting result in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik (Section 3.037).

It states that if $F$ is analytic in the circle of radius $r$ and if:
$$
F\left(re^{i\theta}\right) \ = \ f_1(r,\theta) + i f_2(r,\theta)
$$
Then the following result holds:
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{p}{p^2+\theta^2}\ f_1(r,\theta)\ d\theta \ = \ \frac{\pi}{2} F\left( r e^{-p} \right)
$$

My question is; If you are given a function $f_1$, how do you construct the function $F$ from it? I think it's pretty obvious that you can't always do this, but is there a trick/procedure one can employ in the case that it is possible? Or do you just have to ``guess'' the function $F$?

$\ $

**Context**: I am interested in this result, because I am trying to evaluate the following integral:
$$
\int_0^\infty d\theta\ \frac{p}{p^2 + \theta^2} K_0\left( \sqrt{ \alpha^2 + \beta^2 + 2 \alpha \beta \cosh(\theta) }\ \right)
$$

So essentially, I have $f_1 = K_0\left( \sqrt{ \alpha^2 + \beta^2 + 2 \alpha \beta \cosh(\theta)} \ \right)$ in terms of the G&R result.

Comment: Look up "analytic continuation".

Comment: Isn't it "harmonic conjugate" that's wanted here?

Comment: If $f_2(x,y)$ is a [harmonic conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_conjugate) of $f_1(x,y)$ then $f(z)=f_1+if_2$ (and $if(z)=-f_2+if_1$) are analytic functions. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Oh yes, it looks like that is what I'm looking for! I'm trying to figure this out now. I think if I write $f_1(r,\theta) = K_0( \sqrt{ r^2 + \beta^2 + 2 r \beta \cosh(\theta) } )$, then I can check if $\nabla_{(r,\theta)}^2 f_1(r,\theta)=0$, in which case the harmonic conjugate exists